# Why Butterknife generated R2 file have all identical integer values 0x0 for all resources?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am migrating my project to **AndroidX**. While migrating it seems I need to update butterknife dependency: both project level and module level. After updating dependencies, it seems R2.java file has all resources mentioned but integer value of all is 0x0.

While building project I am getting below error:

error: `Attempt to use @BindView for an already bound ID 0 on 'tvTitle'. (com.cariq.mobility.cariqlib.utils.ui.BillDetailsDialogFrag.tvMessage)`

I tried cleaned project, Restarted with Invalidating cache etc.

> This is some of field from R2.java file for reference.
>       ```@IdRes
>       public static final int etOldPassword = 0x0;

````
@IdRes
public static final int etPanNumber = 0x0;

@IdRes
public static final int etPassword = 0x0;

@IdRes
public static final int etPhoneNum = 0x0;

@IdRes
public static final int etPinCode = 0x0;```
````

I am expecting to compile project and build APK successfully.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this bug https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1549. To fix you should upgrade to ButterKnife 10.2.1+